# Grails taglib only printing one class name

Tags: grails, taglib

I have a custom taglib and i'm passing it some attributes. I want it to output a input field with the attributes I pass in.

```
def selectField = { attrs ->
    System.out.println( attrs.class );
    out << "<input id=" + attrs.id + " class=" + attrs.class + " name=" + attrs.name + " />"
}
```

When I print out class I get this 
*"span2 myinput"*

**Call element in gsp file**

```
<mynamespace:selectField class="span8 myinput" name="pay" id="myid"  data-user="${blaaaa}"/>
```

When I check the input element that was rendered by the selectField method I get this

```
<input id="myid" class="span8" myinput="" name="pay">
```

Can't seem to get it to accept class with multiple names. It seems to accept one string only for the class and then prints the other by itself as another attributes

It should be

```
<input id="myid" class="span8 myinput" name="pay">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are still using String concatenation and no quotes in the output.

This is how the tag should look like:

```
 def selectField = { attrs ->
    out << '<input id="' << attrs.id << '" class="' << attrs.class << '" name="' << attrs.name << '" />'
}
```

you might want to take a look at `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib` source code to see how the tags should be implemented

Comment: Ah worked like a charm. I didn't know I had to add << to each attribute. Is there any good documentation on writing tagLibs that you can recommend.

Comment: there's no special docu on writing taglibs, but reading about groovy essentials (String-processing in your case) would definitely be helpful